# Firebird on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, firebird

Does anybody know on how to install Firebird 2.0 on FreeBSD 7.2? I have updated the ports and the kernels, but when I try to do a "make install", I get the error:

Please do not build firebird as 'root' because this may cause conflicts with SysV semaphores of running services.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you compiling as root?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the reply, guys. I finally figured it out. Here's how:

make -DPACKAGE_BUILDING

make install

that finally got it compiled and installed.

Comment: that's definitely a bug in the port.  consider submitting a PR.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth your while to download the official source from firebird's site instead of using the FreeBSD port. Have a look [here](http://n4.nabble.com/Firebird-2-1-3-and-FreeBSD-7-2-amd64-td1114383.html#a1114383) at someone who posted about compiling firebird on freebsd. There may be a macro that needs to be included to get around your problem. As for the `make install`, I would do this as a normal user first and see what happens. If it fails, then root around looking at the documents to see if there is a macro for compiling and enable it, then recompile the source, and try again.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tom. I finally figured it out. Here's how:

make -DPACKAGE_BUILDING
make install

that finally got it compiled and installed.

Answer (score 1):

I see some patch on Firebird Tracker for [Firebird 2.5](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-2825)

Perhaps, it can be useful for you.